# Youtube audio still playing after removing iframe with jQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, video, youtube

I made a script that shows an Youtube image. After clicking the image, the Youtube video will automatically play. The scripts works like this:

**On click at the image**

- Replace the Youtube iframe with setting autoplay: 1 (to play the video)
- Hide the image
- Show the parent div of the parent div around the Youtube iframe

*In the parent div around the Youtube iframe, i have a div called ".exit" with a .exit button.

**On click at the .exit button**

- Replace the Youtube iframe with setting autoplay: 0 (to stop the video)
- Show the image
- Hide the parent div of the parent div around the Youtube iframe

It works like a charm in Google Chrome and FireFox, but in IE 9 & 10 the audio of the video keeps playing. Even when i .remove() the whole parent div of the Youtube iframe, after clicking the .exit button. In the IE Developer tool you can see the whole div disappears, but you still hear the audio.

**Showing the code**

Here is the code of my function. I made the script like this so i only have to paste a new .video-slide in the html for each Youtube ID.

Html:

```
<div class="video-slide">
    <div class="preview-image">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/%YOUTUBE_ID%/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="yt-video">
        <div class="exit"></div>
        <div class="the-video">
            <iframe class="viddy" width="100%" height="500px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%YOUTUBE_ID%?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
/*YOUTUBE*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //Add uniq slide id to each .video-slide in the div .video-slider
    jQuery(".video-slider").children().each(function(i) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("id_" + (i+1));
    });

    //Add uniq slide id to each .video-slide in the div .video-slider
    jQuery(".video-slider").children().each(function(i) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("id_" + (i+1));
    });

    //Function for each video
    youtubeSlider = function(){
        jQuery('.preview-image', this).click(function() {
            var slideId = jQuery(this).closest('.video-slide').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
                slideIdClass = '.' + slideId;
                youtubeID = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image img').attr('src').split("/")[4];
                youtubeWidth = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('width');
                youtubeHeight = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('height');

                autoPlayVideo(youtubeID,youtubeWidth,youtubeHeight);
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image').hide();
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .yt-video').show();
        });

        var exitId = jQuery('.exit', this);
        jQuery(exitId).click(function() {

            var slideId = exitId.closest('.video-slide').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
                slideIdClass = '.' + slideId;
                youtubeID = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image img').attr('src').split("/")[4];
                youtubeWidth = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('width');
                youtubeHeight = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('height');

                stopPlayVideo(youtubeID,youtubeWidth,youtubeHeight);
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image').show();
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .yt-video').hide();
        });


        function autoPlayVideo(vcode, width, height){
          "use strict";
          jQuery(slideIdClass + " .the-video").html('<iframe class="viddy" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vcode+'?autoplay=1&loop=0&rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>');
        }

        function stopPlayVideo(vcode, width, height){
          "use strict";
          jQuery(slideIdClass + " .the-video").html('<iframe class="viddy" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vcode+'&loop=0&rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>');
        }

    }
    jQuery(".video-slide").each(youtubeSlider);     

});
```

I know about the Youtube API but i finished this script almost.

So what i want to know is: Is there a way to solve this problem?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it!

Strangely IE didn't read the uniq variables the second time. So i had to remove the uniq ID's. This wasn't a problem, because each video slide will get the right iframe code the first time (Read the question: On click at the image - Replace..).

So i changed this:

```
       var exitId = jQuery('.exit', this);
        jQuery(exitId).click(function() {

            var slideId = exitId.closest('.video-slide').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
                slideIdClass = '.' + slideId;
                youtubeID = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image img').attr('src').split("/")[4];
                youtubeWidth = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('width');
                youtubeHeight = jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .viddy').attr('height');

                stopPlayVideo(youtubeID,youtubeWidth,youtubeHeight);
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .preview-image').show();
                jQuery(slideIdClass + ' .yt-video').hide();
        });
```

In to this:

```
     var exitId = jQuery('.exit', this);
        jQuery(exitId).click(function() {

            var youtubeID = jQuery('.preview-image img').attr('src').split("/")[4];
                youtubeWidth = jQuery('.viddy').attr('width');
                youtubeHeight = jQuery('.viddy').attr('height');

                stopPlayVideo(youtubeID,youtubeWidth,youtubeHeight);
                jQuery('.preview-image').show();
                jQuery('.yt-video').hide();
        });
```